# Is there a way to group by purchase order while showing all items on different pages?

Tags: reporting-services

[image]
SELECT purchaseid, shipvia, item description, sum(qty) as qty, ID
FROM database
GROUP BY purchased, itemdescription, shipvia
WHERE ID=@ID

I've tried formatting the table and breaking the page after each group for Purchase ID but purchase ID 123 since it has two quantities it ends up on separate pages. I've tried a parent group as well. Is there a way for me to format the report so the purchase ID's and all the quantities are on one page.
like this
[image]

I am using microsoft report builder.

Comment: You should just need to group by PurchaseID and then set the **rowgroup** pagebreak to "Between" make sure you don't have any other page breaks set.